# Changing another column value in another table on an insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a downloads table and a user table, i want to keep track of the number of downloads for each user. I think the number of downloads column will change when an identical user id is inserted into the downloads table, but how would i change or update the number of downloads value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to write a insert trigger on downloads table that will calculate the no. of downloads of inserted user and will update user table.